# Getting an exception while executing parallel Stream Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, nullpointerexception, java-stream

I am writing a function that calculates the sum of squares of digit for a given number. I am calling this function for a number from 1 to 1000  in parallel. But I am getting an exception some time.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    IntStream stream = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000);
    Map < Integer, Integer > numbers = new TreeMap < > ();
    stream.parallel().forEach(i - > {
        int result = digitSquareSum(i);
        numbers.put(i, result);
    });
    Files.write(Paths.get("result.csv"), () - > numbers.entrySet().stream()
        . < CharSequence > map(e - > e.getKey() + "," + e.getValue())
        .iterator());
}

private static int digitSquareSum(int i) {
    int result = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    while (i != 0) {
        temp = i % 10;
        result = result + temp * temp;
        i = i / 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:590)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.invoke(ForkJoinTask.java:726)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:160)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfInt.evaluateParallel(ForEachOps.java:189)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:233)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.forEach(IntPipeline.java:417)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline$Head.forEach(IntPipeline.java:574)
```

My aim is to write an efficient method that calculates sum of squares of digit of the number and writes it to the csv file in ascending order manner.

Comment: No. You can use TreeMap. But you shouldn't populate it by using forEach. You should instead use Collectors.toMap(). That will populate the map in a thread-safe way. That said, using a parallel stream to do that will probably make is slower than a sequential stream (you should still use Collectors.toMap() with a sequential stream, though)

Comment: using a parallelstream in your code makes little sense, especially if afters you simply write to your file synchronously, a parallel stream comes with quite the overhead, which results in performance loss for little records such as 1000. As for your code you should use collectors in your parallel streams, those are all thread safe

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you are getting this exception, because `TreeMap` is not thread safe. From [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html):

> **Note that this implementation is not synchronized.** If multiple threads
>   access a map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies
>   the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally. (A
>   structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or
>   more mappings; merely changing the value associated with an existing
>   key is not a structural modification.)

I beleive you are using `TreeMap` to preserve the order of your initial numbers. But it's not necessary (and also introduces [side-effects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness)): you could use [Collectors.toList()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) which *collects all the input elements into a List, in encounter order*.

This will also allow you to avoid creation of the second stream to write these numbers to a file:

```
List<String> lines = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 1000)
            .parallel()
            .mapToObj(i -> i + " -> " + digitSquareSum(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
Files.write(Paths.get("result.csv", lines); // the lines will come in the right order
```